# PHP >! operator isn't legit but works

Tags: php, comparison, operators

So I used `>!` comparison operator in PHP 5.6 and it works. It doesn't appear on any operators documentation and I'm confused why does it work and why PHPStorm doesn't complain about it? Even if `!($foo > $bar)` would be the correct syntax..

Comment: Because it is treated like 2 operators - `>` and `!`?

Comment: I assume it’s not `>!`, it’s `>` and the `!` is “not” for the next argument.

Comment: To be explicit: `$foo >! $bar` === `$foo > (!$bar)`

Comment: Reminds me of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c) question from the C side of the site.

Comment: I bet you also didn't know the `$a++<++$a` operator and many others… ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `>!` operator is in fact **two** operators: `>` and `!`. `!` is applied to second argument:

```
var_dump(!4);     // `false`
var_dump(3 >! 4); // `true`
```

How come that last case it `true`:

`var_dump(3 >! 4)` is same as `var_dump(3 >(! 4))` because of [operators precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

- first, applying `!` to `4` gives you `false`
- second, comparing `3` and `false` gives you `true`, because `3` is `truthy` value which is always **greater** than any `falsy`/`false` value.

As a practice you can understand this tricky cases:

```
var_dump(0 > !0);   // false
var_dump(-3 > !0);  // false
```

Comment: True. Now that reading this thread a while later this makes sense and should've been clear to me from the start... ::) thanks

Answer (score 0):

It does not seems to work for me, as a variable comparison operator. In php 5.6, results are inconsistent:

```
$a = 10;
$b = 5;

var_dump($a >! $b);
```

returns `true`

but

```
$a = 10;
$b = 11;

var_dump($a >! $b);
```

returns `true` again

As others have stated, your variable is being evaluated as `false`, which make the if statement to returns true in the code above

Comment: Because `!b` is __false__.

Comment: Well, for *some* definition of "works"… It doesn't produce any syntax error, is probably what OP meant.

Comment: If `$b` != 0, `!$b == false` which is equivalent to `0` in a numeric comparison. So `10 > !5` and `10 > !11`

Comment: exactly it seemed to me that OP was considering it a strange "negation" of variable size comparison